# How can this loop ever exit?

Tags: java, multithreading, testing

So, I ran a test and the results make no sense to me. Lets consider the following code:

```
ThreadStuffCounter counter_1 = new ThreadStuffCounter(1);
while(counter_1.doProceed) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    Thread thread = new Thread(counter_1);
    thread.start();
}
```

With the `Runnable` as follows:

```
package test;

public class ThreadStuffCounter implements Runnable {
    public volatile boolean doProceed = true;
    private int id = -1;
    public volatile int i = -1;
    public ThreadStuffCounter(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("i = " + i + " in runnable id = " + id);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        doProceed = false;
    }
}
```

Only one instance of counter is shared between threads. It takes less time for another thread to start then even one increment to be made on the `counter.doProceed` should, as I understand never be set to false and the loop should continue indefinitely until I get an out of memory exception and cannot start any more threads.

How is it possible for the loop to exit?

EDIT:  Modified code to make sure the answer below is correct.

```
package test;

public class ThreadStuffCounter implements Runnable{

public volatile boolean doProceed = true;
private int id = -1;
volatile int i = -1;
public ThreadStuffCounter(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    i = 0;
    while (i < 10){
        System.out.println("i = " + i + " in runnable id = " + id +
                "; from thead id = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i++;
    }
    ThreadStuff.doProceed = false;
}
```

}

And

```
package test;

public class ThreadStuff {

public static volatile boolean doProceed = true;

public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    ThreadStuffCounter counter_1 = new ThreadStuffCounter(1);
    while(doProceed){
        Thread.sleep(500);
        Thread thread = new Thread(counter_1);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

}

Also, it appears more then n threads are needed if you are running for i < n. You need however many, so that n threads increment at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When at least one of the threads executes the `for` loop and `i` value is greater or equal than 10, then `doProceed` variable will be `false` (yes, this may happen), and since it's `volatile` this will stop the execution of the `while` loop that creates and starts new threads. Then, is up to all the threads to just finish executing the code of the `for` loop and then *finishing* their execution. This seems to happen because the time to start a new thread in your environment is slower than the time for a current thread to finish its execution. Also, note that several threads may increase `i` value, which will accelerate the `for` loop execution.

Probably if you loop to a higher value (not tested) then this could generate an infinite loop and the application will break when there aren't enough resources to create and start new threads.

---

After some tests using the limit as 10, 50 and 1000. I noticed that when you have a bigger value, since lots of threads are created, all of them increase the value of `i` at the same time and `i` slowly starts to get closer to the limit value set in the `for` loop. Description of my current environment:

- OS: Windows 7 Professional 64 bits
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.5GHz
- Ram: 8192MB

Comment: From my understanding every time a new thread starts executing the loop the i should get reset back to 0. Going on that assumption, it makes no sense to me how any one of the loops can ever finish.

Comment: @user1219387 read the comment at the bottom of my answer. The time to start a thread may be slower than the time for another thread to loop from `0` to `10`.

Comment: I just tried it with i < 100. Still same result but much longer. I guess its safe to say a lot more CPU time is required to create a thread then run one increment in the loop, and since I only have 2 total they have to be shared in some way I believe you might still be correct. Over all my mind is still blown but thanks for the input :)

Comment: Good point, after looking at my output from last iteration it looks like you are correct. So, then if the loop is for i < n, once you have n threads active, they would all increment i by 1 n times, and i == n. At that point the nth thread would exit the loop and set the boolean to false. I think this case can be considered closed and thank you again for the input